# Adding #include <boost/asio.hpp> results in "has different size" problems

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, mingw32

As writting a (so far) quite simple C++ application (actually I just began to migrate our app away from Qt and replacing it's features mostly by boost) I encountered 'a common' error as follows:

> (path trimmed)\libboost_system.a(error_code.o): duplicate section
>   .rdata$_ZTSN5boost12noncopyable_11noncopyableE[__ZTSN5boost12noncopyable_11noncopyableE]'
>   has different size
>
> (path trimmed) \libboost_filesystem.a(codecvt_error_category.o):
>   duplicate section
>   .rdata$_ZTSN5boost12noncopyable_11noncopyableE[__ZTSN5boost12noncopyable_11noncopyableE]'
>   has different size

I'm obviously using system and filesystem libraries and everything went smoothly just until now, when included **asio** header

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

because of this single line of code: `return boost::asio::ip::host_name();`

As I understood from boosts documentation, asio is header only library and thus I did not include any other boost library and yet libboost_system and libboost_filesystem started to cause these problems.

I'm working on Win 7, using MinGW. I've built all the boost libs in one shot issuing following two commands:

```
bootstrap mingw
b2 toolset=gcc
```

I used the same MinGW set for it as I'm using now to build my app. And of course am I using these pre-built libraries to link with my app.

When I remove the ASIO include, my build works again.

Please comment if I missed some important part of my configuration for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

The two different translation units that these visible symbols originate from (error_code.o vs. codecvt_error_category.o) have not been compiled using the same flags (or, less likely, different sources for boost/noncopyable.hpp).

This either means that

- your build of boost is inconsistent (was it rebuilt partially? was it inconsistently configured during build? did you update a part of the toolchain partly through?)
- you are using binaries for `boost_system` that are from a different build than the one you use for `boost_filesystem`

It could be that one of the libraries participating in the inconsistency are *indirect* (you might e.g. not be aware that your program uses boost filesystem indirectly, and adding Asio relies on a different boost system).

You could also check that you configure the boost build with the same flags with which you compile your program (the one containing `#include <boost/asio.hpp>` e.g.); this is particularly important on MSVC where linker inputs are selected *automatically* using library `#pragma`s

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm 100% sure that both libs are from the same source. I downloaded the zip file from boost.org and ran the build as described in my question. But as you suggested about the build, there actually is one difference I'm aware of but which did not seem so important to me  (feeling embarrassed). While I built the boost, I used mingw32-make.exe bundled with Qt. To build my app I use make.exe comming from the Msys 1.0.10 package. Could that really be the reason? (can't confirm at the moment as I'm out of office).

Comment: That is definitely the sort of thing you'd be looking for. Google C++ ABI and ODR violation. You can be very glad this got caught by the linker.

Comment: Okay then. First thing in the morning I will rebuild the boost libs using the other make and check all other build params to confirm. Will get back here  to let you know. Thanks!

Comment: So i just rebuilt the boost using the same toolchain I use for my app, replaced the libraries but still getting the same error.

Comment: I also tested it the other way around. Building my app with the Qt Bundle and linking the new Boost libraries made using msys and works fine (without including asio), so I guess the make utility is not the problem.

Comment: The make utility is never the problem :) It's how you use them. I'd double check what made it (more) consistent this time around. Good luck!